# My SUMIFS formula not working correctly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

Please can someone advise me where I am going wrong with my SUMIFS formula. Formula worked fine on calculating my outgoing funds however with the incoming it doesn't seem to want to calculate?

[image]

Your help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: @ScottCraner it is J12 and not J2. Visually data seems to be correct but somewhere user has more space or some other invisible char.

Comment: Probably Col:B, Col:C values or `J12` have some extra spaces, try select the values of these cells and see which is not correct.

Comment: try replace the semi colons with commas

Comment: @PeterH why do you think so?

Comment: @PeterH Some non-English versions of Excel use semicolons as separators in formulas rather than commas.

Comment: I agree with @HakanERDOGAN that the problem is likely to be hidden characters such as spaces. Try `=len(b3)`, `=leng(j12)` and other cells to check whether the values are all as you expect.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input. There was hidden character/space all sorted now. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid having to deal with empty spaces you can use wildcards:

```
SUMIFS(H3:H200,B3:B200,”*INcoming*”,C3:C200,”*”&J12&”*”)
```